# Kafka Streams : Stream Thread failed to lock State Directory

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, topology

I am trying to test my Kafka Streams application. I have built a simple topology where I read from an input topic and store the same data in a state store.

I tried writing unit tests for this topology using TopologyTestDriver. When I run the test, I got encountered with following error.

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LockException: stream-thread [main] task [0_0] Failed to lock the state directory for task 0_0
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.registerStateStores(AbstractTask.java:197)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeStateStores(StreamTask.java:275)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.<init>(TopologyTestDriver.java:403)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.<init>(TopologyTestDriver.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.<init>(TopologyTestDriver.java:228)
    at streams.checkStreams.checkStreamsTest.setup(checkStreamsTest.java:99)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    ....
```

I can see state store getting created locally in /tmp/kafka-streams, but somehow streams thread is unable to get a lock over it. I searched and found that this error might be because of two streams threads are trying to acces it, one has the lock so that other has to wait. But I don't see two streams thread getting created in my code. I am new to this kafka streams and its testing, am I missing any thing here?

Comment: Can you share the topology? I've seen instances where an incorrect Topology results in a code path through the Streams library that intentionally does not lock the store.

Comment: maybe your tests run in parallel and applicationId is the same for both suits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TopologyTestDriver` does not create any background threads, so multi-threading (from KafkaStreams itself) should not be an issue -- however, as @BartoszWardziński pointed out, if your testing framework executed tests in parallel, and you use the same `application.id` in different tests, it may lead to locking issues.

The recommendation for tests is, to generate a random `application.id` to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your tests are not running in parallel a solution could be to call the `close()` method on the `TopologyTestDriver`. This will clean the resources and remove the locks. This is probably best practice for disposable objects anyway.

If running tests in parallel you can set a random `application.id`. The problem with this is if you're using a schema registry and connected to a test registry, this will create potentially thousands of schemes (one for each test).

Your two options here are:

- Have a unique `application.id` per test but which is hard-coded (i.e. the name
  of the test) and not random.
- Don't run your tests in parallel and call `close()` on
  `TopologyTestDriver`

Comment: The TopologyTestDriver is implements Closeable, so the best practice is to create it using the try-with-resources Statement.